# The behavior of an integral related to the inward normal vector near a point of the boundary of a domain

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Inspired by [this Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404803/on-a-characterization-of-inward-unit-normal-vector), I am asking for what kind of non-smooth domains $D$ the following limit
$$
\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{1}{m(D \cap B(x,r))}\int\limits_{D \cap B(x,r)}\frac{z-x}{r}\,m(dz)
$$
where

- $B(x,r)=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid |y-x|<r\}$  is the Euclidean ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$ and
- $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$,

could exist (possibly in a almost-everywhere sense).

Two more or less elementary answers possibly are

- $D$ is a Caccioppoli set and $x$ is a point of its reduced boundary and
- when $D$ has a singular part with finite (electrostatic or Newtonian) capacity (see [this Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358606/on-which-regions-can-greens-theorem-not-be-applied/358667#358667) for reference).

Are there any other cases? Also references are welcome.